# Google Colaboratory local runtime using local GPU

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I'm using Colaboratory and Pytorch to run a GAN that uses an unusual dataset, which is currently stored locally on my machine. To access these files I connected to a local runtime (as per https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html). However, Colaboratory now uses *my own* GPU when running now, which it did not do on previous runs. I know this because current runs run much much slower, as they are using my GTX 1060 6GB instead of Colab's Tesla K80.

I checked this using

`torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)`

Which returns "GeForce GTX 1060 6G" when I am connected locally. This is the case *even with* Edit -> Notebook Settings -> Hardware Accelerator -> "GPU" selected.

However, when I am not connected locally, and instead use the (default) "Connect to hosted runtime" option,

`torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)` does return "Tesla K80".

I've had trouble uploading my dataset to Drive, as it is a large image dataset, and would like to carry on using the local runtime.

How do I use both the local runtime and Colab's amazing Tesla K80? 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691393/jupyter-notebook-gpu

Comment: @manza please consider adding your comment as an answer as it seems to satisfy the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter Notebook - GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691393/jupyter-notebook-gpu)

Answer (score 5):

Colab is using your GPU because you *connected it to a local runtime*. That's what connecting it to your own runtime *means*. It means that you're using *your* machine instead of handling the process on Google's servers. If you want to still use Google's servers and processing capabilities, I'd suggest looking into [connecting your Google Drive to the Colaboratory runtime](https://towardsdatascience.com/downloading-datasets-into-google-drive-via-google-colab-bcb1b30b0166).